# How do you determine a step function to approximate another function?

Tags: real-analysis, approximate-integration, step-function

I have a question here in which I need to explicitly write down a sequence $f_n(x)$ that can approximate $e^x$.

From reading, I known that I need to pick a partition sequence of $x_k$ so that I can take $x_k^*\,\epsilon\,[x_k,x_{k+1})$ so that I can do $f_n(x) = f(x_k^*)$.

The bit I'm having trouble with is how exactly do I know what $f_n(x)$ to pick, and to 'write down explicitly' do I have to pick a maximum n, and partition $x_k$'s?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I've let $x_k = a + \frac{k(b-a)}{n} $ for all k = 0, 1,..., n to split into even partitions. I then defined the step functions to be $$f_n(x) = f(x_k^*)$$ where $x_k^* = \frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2}$. From this then: $$f_n(x) = e^{x_k^*} = e^\frac{x_k+x_{k+1}}{2}$$ on each interval [$x_k,x_{k+1}$).
Using this we get $\int_a^b{e^x dx} = \sum_{k=0}^n{f(x_k^*)\frac{b-a}{n}} = \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n{e^\frac{x_k+x_k+1}{2}}$.

Past this point I don't know how to approximate the integral.

Comment: Are you asked to make this approximation on a specific interval, or is it meant to be on the whole real line?

Comment: @TMGallagher On an interval of [a,b]

Comment: Would something like this work for your purposes: for any positive integer $n$, partition $[a,b]$ into $n$ equal length disjoint subintervals, and take the value of your step function on a given subinterval in your partition to be equal to $f$ evaluated at any point in each sub interval.

Comment: That's along the lines of what I was thinking, but I've never encountered that being described as "explicitly writing down" a sequence of functions. I'll try this.

Comment: Note that it also depends on how you define this sequence to converge.

Comment: @rubikscube09 could you elaborate?